# Are there performance differences for saveInBackground v saveEventually?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Is there any reason to use `saveInBackground` instead of `saveEventually`? Both have callbacks available. Is there any difference in performance or functionality? Are they the exact same function but with `saveEventually` having a network check in it?

My understanding is that they are the same because they're compared in the docs but the docs don't explicitly state that. Does `saveInBackground` get pushed to a higher priority thread than `saveEventually` or is the thread the same?

**Update**:

As there are performance differences as MikeG notes below I made a simple fallback save method for just in case situations. I now employ this everywhere I would run a normal save operation. I `saveInBackground` and then fallback to `saveEventually`:

```
func saveInBackgroundIfNotSuccessSaveEventually(object: PFObject, completion: (() -> ())?) {

object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

    if !success {
        object.saveEventually({ (success, error) -> Void in

            if success {
                completion?()
            }

            if error != nil {
                NSLog(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

    } else if success {
        completion?()
    }

    if error != nil {
        NSLog(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
})
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions are different. `saveInBackground` performs the save asynchronously. That means it calls the save function, and then returns to the calling thread immediately so that functionality may continue without having to wait for the save function to complete and return. I have been using `saveInBackground` in my app and have literally done hundreds of tests and as long as an internet connection is available, this function will be completed within 3 seconds max, usually within 1 second. How this function behaves when no internet connection is available I am unsure, but if you are in a situation in which you are unsure if a connection will be available, but you need to make a save, then go with `saveEventually()`.

`saveEventually` on the other hand will perform the save at some unspecified time in the future. Even if an internet connection is unavailable, it will wait until a connection is available and then perform the save. I believe, though I am not positive, that this function is dispatched to a queue that has quality of service `Background` and thus it is not a high priority task, it can be put off until resources are available at some unspecified time in the future. This could take anywhere from seconds to minutes even up to hours I suppose, if a connection is unavailable for that long.

Edit: forgot to answer the question directly, "Are there performance differences...". Answer is yes!

Comment: You touched on it being dispatched to a queue and that's exactly what I'm wondering whether it gets pushed off to a low priority thread. You believe it does? I will update my question to be more clear.

Comment: Right, I am not positive because I have not read definitive documentation nor gotten definitive results from my own testing as to which thread it is being run on. But I do believe that `saveEventually` is pushed off to a lower priority thread than `saveInBackground`. I think you can get the current thread using something like `let qos = dispatch_queue_get_qos_class(queueInQuestion, nil)`

Answer (score 3):

`saveInBackground` will save in the background while the app is running.

`saveEventually` will add your object to a cache to save to Parse either while your app is running - or not.

If there is no network available:

- `saveInBackground` will retry X number of times while your app is
  running, and eventually it will fail.
- `saveEventually` will keep on trying, regardless of whether your app is running.

Sources:

- "Saving Objects" - https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects
- "Saving Objects Offline" - https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects-offline
- Parse Support forum - answer from cofounder of Parse Kevin Lacker - https://www.parse.com/questions/what-happens-if-i-do-a-saveinbackground-and-then-the-internet-connection-goes-down

Comment: Coulda saved me a lot of typing. Your answer straight forward and concise, thank you.

Comment: Could you tell me where you found the documentation for that? I like to read

Comment: Have added sources to answer.